# I have some example code but i do not understand the parameters

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

I found this example code to login to LinkedIN ,but i do not understand what are CONSUMER_KEY
and CONSUMER_SECRET

```
  /*Consumer settings from linkedin*/
    private string _consumerKey = "Consumer_Kay";
    private string _consumerSecret = "Consumer_Secret";

    public enum Method { GET, POST, PUT, DELETE };
    public const string USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0";
    public const string REQUEST_TOKEN = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken";
    public const string AUTHORIZE = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize";
    public const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken";
    public const string CALLBACK = "liconnect://success";
```

Please tell me from where can i find these values.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These values will be supplied to you by LinkedIn when you sign up for using their API. They are part of the OAuth authentication being used, providing a secure means of authenticating the user.

It is explained on the [Developer pages](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1251).